# Module pattern vs. instance of an anonymous constructor

Tags: javascript, singleton

So there's this so-called *module pattern* for creating singletons with private members:

```
var foo = (function () {
    var _foo = 'private!';
    return {
        foo: function () { console.log(_foo); },
        bar: 'public!'
    }
})();
```

There's also this method that I found on my own, but haven't seen anything written about:

```
var foo = new function () {
    var _foo = 'private!';
    this.bar = 'public!';
    this.foo = function () { console.log(_foo); };
}
```

I'm thinking there must be a reason why nobody writes about this while there's tons of articles about the module pattern. Is there any downside to this pattern? Speed, or browser compatibility perhaps?

Comment: I've used the second before... I thought it was quite common

Comment: They're both essentially the same. It's all down to taste...

Answer (score 13):

In this case it seems you are using only **one instance object** of that **"class"**. So may want to take look at what Douglas Crockford thinks about [putting `new` directly in front of `function`](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/):

> By using **new** to invoke the function, the object holds onto a worthless `prototype` object. That wastes memory with no offsetting advantage. If we do not use the new, we don’t keep the wasted prototype object in the chain. So instead we will invoke the factory function the right way, using ().

So according to the renown javascript architect of Yahoo! you should use the first method, and you have his reasons there.

Comment: You interpretation of my answer is not what I meant nor what I said. I just responded to the question about those 2 specific ways of constructing an object when you will have only an instance of it (as shown in the question). And the context of Crockford's post is exactly the same. But I'd taken your constructive part of your feedback and **I've updated my question** to include the context. So thank you for you commenting your -1.

Answer (score 4):

More-or-less, they give you the same result. It's just a matter of which path you want to take for it.

The 1st may be more popular since it's simply the mixture of 2 already common patterns:

```
(function closure() {
    var foo = 'private';
    /* ... */
}())

var singleton = {
    bar : 'public'
};
```

However, `prototype` chaining would be the benefit of the 2nd pattern since it has its own constructor.

```
var singleton = new function Singleton() { };
assert(singleton.constructor !== Object);

singleton.constructor.prototype.foo = 'bar';
assert(singleton.foo === 'bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any substantial difference between the two.  I would prefer the latter simply since it has much less punctuation clutter.

On the other hand the "module pattern" approach seems to be the most common and is becoming a well known pattern (due to the rise in JQuery).  It might be better to stick with this recognised pattern not because it has any more technical merit than the other approach but just because it will likely be more recognizable (despite the heavy punctuation).

Comment: I don't think it's entirely or even mainly due to the rise in jQuery: it's been around for longer than that.

Answer (score 1):

Douglas Crockford [writes](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) about the second one.  As Greg says in his comments, I thought it was quite common, and I've used it in the past.

Edit: to actually answer your question - there's no downsides, the two are functionally equivalent (both create a closure containing the "private variables" and exposing other variables/methods publically), and have exactly the same browser support and performance characteristics.  It just comes down to a matter of syntax - basically, where you put the `()` to actually invoke this function and get your closure, and whether you use the `new` keyword.

Comment: Actually Douglas Crockford is against the second one. `It is never a good idea to put new directly in front of function. For example, new function provides no advantage in constructing new objects.`
http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/

Comment: I disagree with the "no advantage" assertion.  It's more succinct than the alternative example shown, and succinctness helps readability and maintainability.