# Newbie: Javascript, Jquery Classes and Objects

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am rather confused with mechanics and hierarchy of things in javascript, reading few links and pages are  adding to them.

There are [various ways to create objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109108/javascript-creating-objects-multiple-approaches-any-differences).  What I am getting confused is in following:

I have 3 websocket say WSServiceA, WSServiceB, WSServiceC : These are 3 different sockets and provide different data but data structure is same. Using a simple function I am updating 3 tables in web-page.

Each of these have onopen, onclose and onmessage function so I have simply copied same code 3 times, like this:

```
WSServiceA.onmessage(){}
WSServiceB.onmessage(){}
WSServiceC.onmessage(){}
```

If I create a something like this:

```
function CreateService(Service, WSAddress){
      this.service=Service;
      this.WSAddress = WSAddress;
      this.websocket = new WebSocket(this.WSAddres);
      this.onopen = function(event){ Send some message }
      this.onmessage = function(event){ Update Table A}
    }
```

After that I will create

```
ServiceA = CreateService("A", "ws://192.168.100.1.1:10001");
ServiceB = CreateService("B", "ws://192.168.100.1.2:10001");
ServiceC = CreateService("C", "ws://192.168.100.1.3:10001");
```

Then how and who will call ServiceA.onopen, Service.onmessage and other functions - when data comes to those sockets? Will it be called at all? Something created inside function should be visible only in that function - I am not able to understand flow and link. Probably I am missing some key concept or this should not work.

Comment: in onopen function you should have access to the socket by refering to `this`, if not, you can create a function with `bind` to bind it to an object

Comment: Perhaps start with the [*The WebSocket API spec*](https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/). If you don't understand events, perhaps [*quirksmode: Introduction to Events*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) will help.

Comment: these `.on` * are **event listeners** When the respective event will fire, they will be listening for it and will execute the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Background

There is ECMAScript, which is the language, and javascript, which is a generic name for an implementation of ECMAScript for a particular host (noting that JavaScript™ is a trademark of Oracle Corporation).

ECMAScript by itself does very little, it doesn't even have a mechanism for input or output, it must be provided by the host. In regard to WebSockets, if the host supports them then it will implement the [*WebSockets API*](https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/).

When you create a WebSocket through `new WebSocket(...)`, then the host returns a host object that implements the interface.  The object will have a state that changes in response to its environment (connecting, open, closing, closed) and it will dispatch events when certain things happen.

When the socket successfully makes a connection to the server, it will dispatch an *open* event on the socket, so that if there is an *onopen* listener, it will respond to the event by being called by the *open* handler. There are also events for *error* and *close* that have associated *on** handlers.

#### Answer

> Then how and who will call ServiceA.onopen, Service.onmessage and
>   other functions - when data comes to those sockets?

The host environment implementing the interface does all that.